# QOpenGLContext vs QGLWidget, differences?

Tags: qt, opengl, qt5

What are the differences between QOpenGLContext and QGLWidget? Which one should I use if I need openGL in my Qt app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what are the differences between QOpenGLContext and QGLWidget?

QOpenGLContext - creates OpenGL context.

QGLWidget - if it has no parent, it is going to create a window, and it will create a new OpenGL context. If it has a parent, it will add a new OpenGL context. Also, it is possible to reuse OpenGL context from other window.

> Which one should I use if I need openGL in my Qt app?

If you new in OpenGL, then until you learn more, use QGLWidget to open a window or create an OpenGL widget.